# Python Pandas - How to get the (iloc) position of one or more filtered rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': 
                  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']},
                  index=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 30])
```

With **df.iloc**[x] I can get the row x in the dataframe. For example.

```
df.iloc[3]
```

returns

letters    D
Name: 40, dtype: object

When I filter the dataframe like

```
df2 = df.iloc[1:3]
```

I get for df2

```
    letters
20  B
30  C
```

Now assume that I didn't know how the filter was applied and I need to find out the values for the filtered rows (1 and 2).

What's the best way to get the list of positions, that allow me to access a filtered result like this result in via the original dataframe using **df.iloc** ? How do I get the position numbers?

**I am looking for the result**

```
[1, 2]
```

Note: I had a good suggestion:

```
df.index.get_indexer_for((df2.index))
```

which doesn't work, if the index is not unique.

```
Int64Index([1, 2, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(20):df.index.get_loc(30)+1]` (unlike loc, iloc excludes the last element so you need to add 1).

Comment: @user2285236 the linked answer doesn't explain how to get the numbers, your example uses the index example (20, 30). Assuming I don't know, how df2 is filtered, how do I get the positions? I changed the question to make it more clear.

Comment: `df.index.get_indexer_for(df2.index)`?

Comment: @user2285236 Thanks, that works for this example, but doesn't work if the index contains doubles. I will amend the question to show that. Because I am looking for only the positions of the filtered result.

Comment: Note that in modern pandas, df.loc[20:30] won't even work, _because_ 30 is non-unique.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I used this only to get a quick filter example (I still have 0.19.2 on this machine), AFAIK modern pandas still allows non unique indexes, where locating via the index would fail That's why I'm looking to extract the list of positions.

Answer (score 0):

Because we have to incorporate the value as well if we want to handle cases like `df.iloc[[1,5]]`, where you'd need to get 5 from "30 F", I think the easiest way is to leverage a merge:

```
In [172]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[1:3].reset_index())
Out[172]: 
   level_0  index letters
0        1     20       B
1        2     30       C

In [173]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[1:3].reset_index())["level_0"].values
Out[173]: array([1, 2], dtype=int64)

In [174]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[[1,5]].reset_index())
Out[174]: 
   level_0  index letters
0        1     20       B
1        5     30       F

In [175]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[[1,5]].reset_index())["level_0"].values
Out[175]: array([1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

In the case where it's not possible to uniquely recover original positions because of duplicate rows, you'll get all of them:

```
In [179]: df.iloc[-1, 0] = "C"

In [180]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[[1,2]].reset_index())
Out[180]: 
   level_0  index letters
0        1     20       B
1        2     30       C
2        5     30       C

In [181]: df.reset_index().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[[1,2]].reset_index())["level_0"].values
Out[181]: array([1, 2, 5], dtype=int64)
```

but you can decide how you want to drop duplicates after the merge.